# ValueError when adding metrics=["accuracy"] into keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, valueerror

I am trying to create a sequential MLP model using keras (version 2.3.1) and tensorflow (version 1.13.1).

I create the model like this:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[24, 49]),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax")
])
```

then compile it like this:

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
            metrics=["accuracy"])
```

which **throws error**:

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("metrics/acc/Cast_6:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)'
```

**BUT** if I remove the line `metrics=["accuracy"]`, the code **compiles without error**. I have seen some people cast using tf.cast() but I am not sure where that would go here.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sparse_categorical_accuracy`, if you're using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function.

Comment: Can you explain why?